# mysql select static list

Tags: mysql

I want to run an

```
INSERT ... SELECT
```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

query to insert **1 selected column column with the exact amount of 2 rows** from one table to another.

Along with this I would like to insert an additional column of static values.

**Example**

```
| selected column | static val |
     Variable          4              
     Variable          9
```

static values 4 & 9 are specified in my php script.
Can I do this in 1 mysql query, not using php to store temporary data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to select from the source table twice like this:

```
insert into new_table
   select column, 4 from old_table
union all
   select column, 9 from old_table;
```